# Time Series and Moving Average

Tags: time-series, self-study, moving-average

I just recently started to learn about moving average process of order 1, however, I get confused if there are other things attached to the equation.

1. For example: $Z_t = 8 + 2t + 5X_t$ where $X_t$ is a zero-mean stationary series with autocovariance function $r_k$

a) Find the mean function and the autocovariance function of $Z_t$.

I am guessing:

Mean = $E[Z_t]=E[8+2t+5X_t]=E[8]+2E[t]+E[X_t]=0$

Covariance = $Cov[Z_t,Z_t]=E[Z_tZ_t]=E[8+2t+5X_t][8+2t+5X_t]=r_k^2$

Can someone please tell me if I did this correct?

2. The questions says $X_t$ is a zero-mean, unit variance, stationary process with autocorrelation function $p_k$.

Then how do I find the mean, variance, and auto covariance of $Z_t = 8 + 2t + 4tX_t$?

Mean = $E[Z_t]=E[8+2t+4tX_t]=E[8]+2E[t]+4tE[X_t]=0$ ?

Variance = No idea

Covariance = I guess I just have to use

$$corr(x,x)=cov(x,x)/\sqrt{var(x)var(x)}?$$

Comment: Let's start at the beginning. Why do you think that $E[8]+2E[t]+E[X_t]=0$?

Comment: How is this related to *moving average*? I think the title and the `moving-average` tag may be irrelevant.

Comment: I was thinking this was a moving average process with order of 0? So as you can see from the expected value equation of the 1st question, E[8] is a constant so it is 0, E[X_t]=0 is already given, and since mean does not relate to time so E[t]=0?

Comment: $E[8]$ is the expected value of a random variable that is constant at 8. What is this expected value? Similarly, $E[t]$ is the expected value of the random process that takes the deterministic value $t$ at time $t$. What is this expected value? Note that in time series, you almost never integrate out time. You are interested in properties of your random process *at time $t$*.

Comment: Ohh so
Mean = $E[Z_t]=E[8+2t+5X_t]=E[8]+2E[t]+E[X_t]=8+2μ_t$? If this is the case? This is not a stationary process since the mean depends on time?